# Discord.js Modal ValidationError

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

I'm attempting to make a bot but when I try to show the user a modal, I get the following error:

`ValidationError: Expected the value to be a string or number`

I'm not sure why this happens, but here is the code which seems to be causing it:

```
await interaction2.showModal(
  new ModalBuilder()
    .setTitle("Create new field.")
    .setCustomId("newtemplatefield")
    .setComponents(
      ...[
        new ActionRowBuilder<TextInputBuilder>().addComponents(
          ...[
            new TextInputBuilder().setLabel("Field Name").setCustomId("fieldname").setRequired(true)
          ]
        ),
        new ActionRowBuilder<TextInputBuilder>().addComponents(
          ...[
            new TextInputBuilder()
              .setLabel("Field Description")
              .setCustomId("fielddesc")
              .setRequired(true)
          ]
        )
      ]
    )
);
```

Comment: Can you include the full error message with stack trace? We can't tell what field is throwing the ValidationError, or if this is even the code causing the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discord.js error messages leave a lot to be desired, but the validation error is really a missing required part of the text input. You need to set the `TextInputStyle` with `.setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short)` or `.setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph)`

Check out the sample modal in [the Discord.js docs](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/modals.html#building-and-responding-with-modals).